# Как организовать обработку данных мобильного приложения?

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

Приложение учета расходов, похожее на CoinKeeper. Под своим вопросом я подразумеваю два пути:

1) Обработка информации (добавление расходов, постановка целей, изменение текущего баланса свободных средств и т.д.) происходит в самом приложении и на сервер отсылается уже обработанная информация.

2) Обработка информации происходит на сервере и приложение получает только готовые данные и отображает их.

Я понимаю, что указанные мной способы служат разным целям и  являются удобными для определенных ситуаций. Но я не знаю для каких. Мне предстоит сделать выбор среди этих вариантов, но я даже не знаю плюсов и минусов каждого из них. Можете прояснить ситуацию, при каких обстоятельствах выбрать первый вариант, а при каких - второй?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от твоих целей, которые ты не озвучил, в записимости от окружения, команды, денег, повернутых на тех или иных идеях менеджеров.

К примеру, твоя задача - написать мобильное приложение. Хочешь ли ты заниматься бизнес-логикой или ее можно спихнуть на команду бекенда и пусть они дальше с этим страдают? Или быть может, ты сам тоже команда бекенда и работать с данными на стороне сервера тебе будет удобнее? Что у нас представляет собой бекенд? Если это сервак за 5 баксов в месяц, а расчеты достаточно сложные, то лучше всего все делать на клиенте, чем мучать и без того слабенький сервер.

Иными словами, дать ответ на этот вопрос мы не можем, тебе нужно решать самому, за что тебе деньги и платят.

Comment: Деньги мне не платят пока - я  учусь. Приложение пишу с тем, чтобы разобраться в нескольких технологиях андроид, заиметь портфолио, пользоваться самому данным приложением и со временем, возможно, вывести его на коммерческие рельсы. Поэтому получается и бэкенд и фронтэнд - все моя забота.

Comment: Я уже не учусь, давно разобрался в технологиях Андроида и у меня есть портфолио. И как человек с этим опытом могу сказать: вопрос не имеет отношения ни к Андроиду, ни к коммерческому программированию. И если ты не разберешьс в нем, то тоже будешь обитать на стековерфлоу-ру и отвечать на глупые вопросы новичков, которые не очень понимают, чего же они хотят.

Comment: Ну а есть краткий ответ типа:"Хочешь получить кроссплатформенность с высокими затратами на содержание сервера, то второй вариант. Если хочешь сэкономить на серваке, но при этом  снизить скорость работы приложения, то первый вариант". ? Я хочу понять преимущества и недостатки обоих вариантов, потом примерить их на свое приложение и сделать выбор. Новичку положено задавть глупые вопросы..
Вот вы написали, что вариант выбирается в зависимости от целей. мне бы и хотелось понять в каких целях используют какие варианты. Ведь явно, к примеру, нельзя использовать 2 вариант, если у тебя нет бюджета.

Comment: Если у тебя нет бюджета, то это тебе и не надо (ц) кто-то со швабры.  Если нет денег, то это не помешает писать грамотно, чтобы хватило дешевого хостинга, равно как и не помешает сразу монетизировать свой проект. А вот разбираться в тонкостях того, что именно тебе следует использовать, ты начнешь лет эдак через 5 разработки, попробовав оба варианта (и еще кучу других).